# best way to create a mat from a CIImage?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv, opencv3.0

I am using CIDetector to detect faces, then using OpenCV on the lower half of each face to detect the size of any smiles. I am using the below code to create the cv::mat which OpenCV can perform the detection on, as you can see the image goes through the steps `CIImage` -> `Cropped CIImage` -> `NSBitmapImage` -> `CGImage` -> `cv::mat`.

```
- (void)OpenCVdetectSmilesIn:(CIFaceFeature *)faceFeature usingImage:ciFrameImage
{
    CGRect lowerFaceRectFull = faceFeature.bounds;
    lowerFaceRectFull.size.height *=0.5;
    CIImage *lowerFaceImageFull = [ciFrameImage imageByCroppingToRect:lowerFaceRectFull];


    NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:lowerFaceImageFull] autorelease];
    CGImage *lowerFaceImageFullCG = rep.CGImage;
    //TODO: find alternative method of creating cv::mat from ciFrameImage.

    std::vector<cv::Rect> smileObjects;
    cv::Mat frame_gray;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(lowerFaceImageFullCG);
    CGFloat cols = lowerFaceRectFull.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = lowerFaceRectFull.size.height;
    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                    cols,                      // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                     // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), lowerFaceImageFullCG);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    cvtColor( cvMat, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

    smileCascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, smileObjects, 1.1, 0, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, cv::Size(30, 30) );
```

It is working, but I get a crash every now and then in the `NSBitmapImageRep` line, I cannot find a pattern to reproduce the crash though. I am not sure about this but some sort of "instinct" is telling me that my method of creating the cv::mat image from the CIImage is messy and inefficient - not to mention I suspect that the CPU is being unnecessarily used for the NSBitmapImageRep step, whereas all of the others remain in the GPU... Am I right?

Does anyone know a better method of creating the cv::mat from a cropped frame?

Note that ciFrameImage comes from the sample buffer delegate method:

```
CIImage *ciFrameImage = [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:cvFrameBuffer options:settings];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to get rid of the crash: use `createCGImage:fromRect` to skip the `NSBitmapImageRef` step:

```
- (void)OpenCVdetectSmilesIn:(CIFaceFeature *)faceFeature usingImage:ciFrameImage
{
    CGRect lowerFaceRectFull = faceFeature.bounds;
    lowerFaceRectFull.size.height *=0.5;
    CIImage *lowerFaceImageFull = [ciFrameImage imageByCroppingToRect:lowerFaceRectFull];

    // Create the context and instruct CoreImage to draw the output image recipe into a CGImage
    if( self.context == nil ) {
    self.context = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:nil options: nil];
    }
    CGImageRef lowerFaceImageFullCG = [_context createCGImage:lowerFaceImageFull fromRect:lowerFaceRectFull];
```

make sure to

```
    CGImageRelease(lowerFaceImageFullCG);
```

after you're done with it.

Comment: would be great if you could share code that transform CGImageRef to cv::Mat in your answer